# Git commits lost

Tags: git

My team's git has some commit, I can see the changes in commit, but cant see the changes in the file content. And when I show the log of specify file, these commit are not showed.

When I run `git log --stat HeroCombine.lua`

I got:

```
commit eb4ceb8b95fcdab4bbd4737710a9cbdffa3f3708
Author: zhangzhexi <443667351@qq.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 13 22:38:15 2014 +0800

    Fight Win UI

 source/SplCardClient/SplCardClient/Resources/lua/HeroCombine.lua | 5 +----
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 4 deletions(-)
```

When I run `git log --stat --follow HeroCombine.lua`

I got:

```
commit ce8d69ae6e43d908f45f14247b55500d440262d7
Author: zhangzhexi <443667351@qq.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 15 22:12:35 2014 +0800

    Auto jump to pos in list

 source/SplCardClient/SplCardClient/Resources/lua/HeroCombine.lua | 7 ++-----
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)

commit 5f7c4e72afab9f3076ec8cdab7b27a30f4c95f21
Author: zhangzhexi <443667351@qq.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 15 21:51:33 2014 +0800

    Update data in codes

 source/SplCardClient/SplCardClient/Resources/lua/HeroCombine.lua | 9 +++++++++
 1 file changed, 9 insertions(+)

commit 8a2a826502147cb68ceee43713af47283d2c9d5a
Author: zhangzhexi <443667351@qq.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 15 21:25:55 2014 +0800

    Add close to Hero Combine UI

 source/SplCardClient/SplCardClient/Resources/lua/HeroCombine.lua | 13 ++++++++++---
 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

commit eb4ceb8b95fcdab4bbd4737710a9cbdffa3f3708
Author: zhangzhexi <443667351@qq.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 13 22:38:15 2014 +0800

    Fight Win UI

 source/SplCardClient/SplCardClient/Resources/lua/HeroCombine.lua | 5 +----
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 4 deletions(-)
```

But `HeroCombine.lua` file looks stay at the version `eb4ceb8`, every thing commit after are lost.

Comment: Your question doesn't make it completely clear what problem you are having, exactly. However, you can always use `git log -p --follow HeroCombine.lua` to review the exact changes to the file paired with commits that introduced them. That should make it obvious where the changes you have and don't want (or want and don't have) have mysteriously appeared (or disappeared).

Comment: My question is the HeroCombine.lua file stay at the older version. Changes in later commit are lost. And the later commits are not show in git log when without --follow options.

Comment: I guess the file was moved and `git log --follow` finds its new location, while your checkout still has both the old one and the new one. Find the latest location of the file with a command such as `find | grep HeroCombine.lua`.

Comment: File "HeroCombine.lua" location have no problem. Maybe some one move it to other location then move it back? But I don't see any move in git log.

Comment: Can you rerun the `log --follow` command with `--decorate`

Comment: Tried with --decorate, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Someone from your team created and published that commit, and only you cannot see it in your files?

Maybe you've just `fetch`'ed the remote commits, but did not merge or rebase your local over them. Btw. have you branched from their code, or are you working on the same branch?

Before you dive into more complex commands, please [try with `pull` first](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/21/pushing-and-pulling.html). If you have everything set up as usual, then it's probably the easiest way to get and apply newest commits.

edit: wait, I've noticed that the author of everything is 'zhangzhexi' and it somewhat matches your 'John Zhang'. You don't see your own commits? Are you sure that it was '--follow'? have you renamed or moved the file? Were you playing with `merge` or `reset` commands lately? have you tried cleaning and cloning the repo from scratch?

Comment: I try check on other peoples pc, it is as same as my status. I also check my local master, there is no difference between origin/master. I have no commits for this file, only one man modify this file who's name is "zhangzhexi'. We try clone from scratch, same problem. I think mabye some one broken the repo, but I don't know how to find out.